# Why isn't some CSS being applied in the content script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I am using a content script to inject code into websites. The issue is that while most of the css and js is working properly, one batch of css is not being applied. The css for the container that will have the whole thing stick to the bottom of the screen is not being applied at all. I know the css is proper because I can add it in the developer tools on a live site and it works. Why isn't it being applied by the extension? 
I just want to reitterate it is only the `t_inject_container` that isn't being applied, everything else is working.

**CSS:**

```
  /*----------------*/
 /*----Main Page---*/
/_---------- -----*/
.t_inject_container
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color:grey;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.menu {
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.t_intect_button {
    background-color:blue;
    display:block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border-radius:5px;
}

 /*-----------------*/
 /*Timeline Element*/
/*----------------*/
.timeline_element {
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:5px;

}
.t_text_area {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    //$(".add_button").click(add_timeline_element);

    function add_timeline_element(){
        var text_input = $('<input />', {
            type: "text",
            class: "t_text_area"
        });
        var button = $('<button />', {
            text: '-',
            class: "t_intect_button",
            click: function() {$(this).parent().remove();}
        });
        var timeline_element = $('<td />', {
            class: "timeline_element"
        });
        timeline_element.append(button);
        timeline_element.append(text_input);
        $(".t_inject_row").append(timeline_element);
    }

    function create_twitter_bar(){
        var table_container = $("<table />", {
            class: "t_inject_container"
        });
            var row = $("<tr />", {
                        class: "t_inject_row"
                        });
                var menu = $("<td />", {
                    class: "menu"
                });
                    var add_element_button = $("<button />", {
                        text: '+',
                        class: "add_button t_intect_button",
                        click: function() {add_timeline_element();}
                    });
                    var minimize_button = $("<button />", {
                        text: 'm',
                        class: "minimize_button t_intect_button"
                    });
                    menu.append(add_element_button);
                    menu.append(minimize_button);
            row.append(menu);
        table_container.append(row);
        $("body").append(table_container);
    }

    create_twitter_bar();
});
```

**Manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "injection",
    "description": "samples at code injection",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
            "css":["style.css"],
            "js":["jquery-2.1.0.min.js", "index.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [ "<all_urls>", "storage" ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe css isnt't working because of broken comment in line 3...

Comment: Well it gave me the reputition to write comments at least ... ;)

Comment: @Martin and OP +2 rep ;).